# Create dataframe of percentage of each group

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe,

```
´data = {'ID':[279, 224, 221, 329, 333],
    'GROUP':['BLACK', 'BLACK', 'BLUE', 'GREEN','BLACK'],
    'ITEM_1':['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Delhi', 'Kannauj', 'Delhi'],
    'ITEM_2':['Msc', 'Kanpur', 'Kanpur', 'Phd', 'Kanpur']}´

´df = pd.DataFrame(data)´
´df = df.set_index('ID')´

 ID  Group    Item_1   Item_2
279    A      Delhi    Msc
224    A      Kanpur   Kanpur        
221    B      Delhi    Kanpur    
329    C      Kannauj  Phd
333    A      Delhi    Kanpur
```

How can create the following dataframe, with the row equal to differents items and columns with the group, i.e.,

```
            Delhi      KANPUR       Kannauj    Msc      Phd                  
   A         2/6%       3/6%         0%       1/6%      0%
   B         1/2%       1/2%         0%        0%       0%
   C           0%         0%       1/2%        0%     1/2%
```

I mean, construct a dataframe with percentaje respect to the total of each group. Any idea will be appreciated. I thouhg use groupby(['GROUP']) and .apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis=1), but is not how I need this dataframe

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First merge these columns single column:

```
all_items = pd.concat([df.ITEM_1, df.ITEM_2])
all_items
Out[8]: 
ID
279      Delhi
224     Kanpur
221      Delhi
329    Kannauj
333      Delhi
279        Msc
224     Kanpur
221     Kanpur
329        Phd
333     Kanpur
dtype: object
```

Then, merge it back to df:

```
temp_df = pd.concat([df[["GROUP"]].copy(), df[["GROUP"]].copy()])
temp_df["ITEM"] = all_items
temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
temp_df["temp_col"] = 1
temp_df
Out[15]: 
    ID  GROUP     ITEM  temp_col
0  279  BLACK    Delhi         1
1  224  BLACK   Kanpur         1
2  221   BLUE    Delhi         1
3  329  GREEN  Kannauj         1
4  333  BLACK    Delhi         1
5  279  BLACK      Msc         1
6  224  BLACK   Kanpur         1
7  221   BLUE   Kanpur         1
8  329  GREEN      Phd         1
9  333  BLACK   Kanpur         1
```

Pivote it finally,

```
my_pivot = temp_df.pivot_table(values="temp_col", index="GROUP", columns="ITEM", aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
my_pivot = my_pivot / len(df)
# my_pivot / len (df) # <-- changing this to
to_div = my_pivot.aggregate(np.sum, axis=1) # <-- this and
my_pivot = my_pivot.div(to_div, axis=0) # <-- this
Out[31]: 
    ITEM      Delhi  Kannauj  Kanpur       Msc  Phd
GROUP                                          
BLACK  0.333333      0.0     0.5  0.166667  0.0
BLUE   0.500000      0.0     0.5  0.000000  0.0
GREEN  0.000000      0.5     0.0  0.000000  0.5
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have a doubt, for example the group green only has 2 items, then it should be has a value of 0.5 not 0.2

Comment: I mean, the value in the dataframe is the percentage for each group. For instance, Delhi black, is 2/6